# Smooth jquery transitions

Tags: jquery, html

I have this javascript which brings in new content and replaces the old but the transition in which it does this is ugly, it feels just like a regular link.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// initial
$('#content').load('content/index.html');

// handle menu clicks
$('div#nav ul li a').click(function() {
var page = $(this).attr('href');
$('#content').load('content/' + page + '.html');

return false;
});
});
```

How can I add in a transition to make navigation my site more fluid?

I've tried .fadeIn but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Have you looked at css transitions? http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: check out the documentation for jQuery's fadeOut. You could fade out the #content and then load something into it once fadeOut is done inside the callback function

Comment: how doesn't fadeIn _work_ for you? what do you expect it to do?

Comment: If you want to look at CSS transitions, please use the official specification instead of w3schools. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$('#content').fadeOut('fast',function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.load('content/' + page + '.html',function(){
             $this.fadeIn('fast');
        });
});
```

Comment: Since I think that .load is done asynchronously you may want to put fadeIn inside of the callback function for .load so it only fades back in when the content is done loading

Comment: should use the callback for load as .fadeIn after the load does not ensure that the ajax call is completed

Answer (score 1):

I would use the complete callbacks on the [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) and the [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) methods to accomplish this.

Note: Utilizing the complete function on the .fadeOut() is not necessary but it ensures that you do not start loading content until the element is completely out of site.  This will keep from strange flickering when the AJAX call returns really fast

```
var $content; 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $content = $('#content');
  // initial
  $content.fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $content.load('content/index.html', function() {
      $content.fadeIn("slow");
    });
  })


  // handle menu clicks
  $('div#nav ul li a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $content.fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $content.load('content/' + page + '.html', function() {
        $content.fadeIn("slow");
      });
    })

    return false;
  });
});
```

Now here is a bit more to make your code easier to maintain

```
var changeContent = function(page) {
  var $content = $(content);
  $content.fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $content.load('content/' + page + '.html', function() {
      $content.fadeIn("slow");
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  changeContent("index");

  // handle menu clicks
  $('div#nav ul li a').click(function() {
    changeContent($(this).attr('href'));        
    return false;
  });
});
```